# How to include dependency jar files into jar file

Tags: java, jar, compilation, execution

I'm build a jar file with code that uses other jar files as dependencies, and I can't get it to run (I keep getting a NoClassDefFoundError).

All the other similar issues I could find online used maven as a solution, which I want to avoid doing. When I run my code like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp "src/.:src/jsoup-1.9.2.jar:src/commons-cli-1.3.1.jar" WikipediaWords $@
```

it runs fine, but when I try:

```
java -cp "src/.:src/jsoup-1.9.2.jar:src/commons-cli-1.3.1.jar" -jar WikipediaWords.jar $@
```

it complains.

I compile my jar file with all the dependencies inside, though, so I really have no clue why it can't find anything. Ideally, I wouldn't even want to have to add the -cp path to my java execution, and just have the jar file know to use the nested jar dependency files.

If you have any clue about how to solve this (run the jar file without class def error) without the use of Maven, please let me know!

Thanks in advance!

P.S. My building code might be of use:

```
#!/bin/bash
javac -cp "src/.:src/jsoup-1.9.2.jar:src/commons-cli-1.3.1.jar" src/WikipediaWords.java
jar cfm src/WikipediaWords.jar src/Manifest.txt -C src/ .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the below command:

```
java -cp "src/.:src/jsoup-1.9.2.jar:src/commons-cli-1.3.1.jar:WikipediaWords.jar" WikipediaWords $@
```

OR

```
java -cp "WikipediaWords.jar:src/.:src/jsoup-1.9.2.jar:src/commons-cli-1.3.1.jar" WikipediaWords $@
```

Comment: Do you have any clue if I could somehow source to the copies of the jar files inside of WikipediaWords.jar?

Comment: Its not a good practice to copy source file to a jar file. Why you want to include source file in your jar file?

Comment: Could you accept the answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: Yes sorry it blocked me from accepting before because it was too fast. I want the jar file to be standalone, so I could execute it without the other libraries (jsoup and commons-cli). Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122783/discussion-between-krishna-kuntala-and-ofek-gila).